# Evaluate $\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{n+\cos^n(e^x)}{4n+x^4} dx$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, riemann-integration

Evaluate $\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{n+\cos^n(e^x)}{4n+x^4} dx$

Attempt: We define $f_n(x)=\frac{n+\cos^n(e^x)}{4n+x^4}$ on the domain $(0,1)$.

This sequence of functions $(f_n)$ converges pointwise to $\frac{1}{4}$. This is dominated by $g(x)=\frac{1}{2}$.

The set $[0,1]$ is measureable and continuous functions are measureable as well.

Now, using Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem,  we can interchange the limit and we finally get $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{4}dx=\frac{1}{4}$.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Why do you think you went wrong here? What do you or another source think the answer should be?

Comment: I have received some feedbacks that this process is not true (from a few professors).

Comment: but I missed entirely the "why" part @J.G.

Comment: @SubhasisBiswas This is quite standard, I can't imagine why you had a negative feedback from your professors. What kind of professors are we talking about? What was the argument?

Comment: Well, it might be the case that in that answer I considered the $\sigma$ ring to be the subsets of $[0,1]$

Comment: my footing is weak here

Comment: Another way (without DCT): $\frac{n-1}{4n+1}\le f_n(x)\le\frac{n+1}{4n}$.

Comment: this is pretty nice. I am going to upload an image for you to check. Will that be alright? I need this. This is driving me insane.

Comment: part 1 https://ibb.co/BPC3h2q , part 2 https://ibb.co/kSVt9R2

Comment: sorry for the pathetic handwriting.