# how can i find $\lim _ { n \rightarrow \infty } \int _ { 0 } ^ { \pi / 2 } e ^ { - n \sin x } d x$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

i need to find $\lim _ { n \rightarrow \infty } \int _ { 0 } ^ { \pi / 2 } e ^ { - n \sin x } d x$
What i tried: $$\left|\int _ { 0 } ^ { \pi / 2 } e ^ { - n \sin x }\mathrm{d}x\right|\leq\int _ { 0 } ^ { \infty } |e ^ {-nx}| \mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{n}$$ so integral equals to $0$. Is it right?

Comment: I think you can conclude that the absolute value of the integral (as function of $n$) is at most $\int_0^\infty|\exp(-n\sin x)|dx$, but not at most $\int_0^\infty|e^{-nx}|dx$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inequality you have used is not correct. For a correct proof use the well known inequality $\sin\,x \geq \frac 2 {\pi} x$ for $x \in (0,\pi/2)$. You can now evaluate the integral and s how that the limit is $0$.

Comment: now we can apply the dominated convergence theorem?

Comment: No need for DCT.You can write down the exact value of $\int_0^{\pi /2}e^{-2nx/ \pi}\, dx$.

Comment: this is great! But, sir I need some help regarding this question. I really need some assurance that my procedure is correct here. I am posting this link because I think this might be relevant to this question. 

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3228074/evaluate-lim-n-to-infty-int-01-fracn-cosnex4nx4-dx 

I have received a negative feedback regarding the procedure from my professors (not in person though, due to some problems). This might seem very unprofessional here, but I cannot help but ask everyone around for verification.

Comment: within the prescribed syllabus, this problem is a straightforward application of Dini's theorem. But I am trying to apply a more generalised approach here.

Comment: @SubhasisBiswas You have been assured by many that your argument is correct and your professor is wrong. Is it possible he expected a proof without use of DCT?

Answer (score 3):

Let $f_n(x)= e^{-n \sin x}$. Then $f_n \to 0$ a.e. on $[0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$ and $|f_n| \le 1$ for all $n$ on $[0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$.

Now invoke the Dominated Convergence Theorem.

Comment: this might be very much illegal on MSE, but I request you to check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3228074/evaluate-lim-n-to-infty-int-01-fracn-cosnex4nx4-dx

Comment: This is also an application of DCT.